# I need to know how to set up an old computer to be a multiple instance Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, ssh, virtualization, hardware, headless

This may sound quite ignorant, I'm not by any means an expert on this subject, so forgive me if I ask something that's quite easy for you all.

I've been searching for multiple instances I need for a scrapping job. I need 12 servers running 2G 2C 20Gb each, and I've done my math, and I'm better off using an old computer I have laying around. It's an old 1600 AF stacked with 16GB and an ssd, so it's more than enough.

My question is, is there a basic software that I can use to run 6 instances at the same time, each with 2 Threads 2.5GB Ram, doing pretty basic stuff. Eventually if this works, I'll buy a second one.

This pseudo-server would cost me around $270 worth of parts (on my Home country using some spares) and to rent such servers costs $65 / month. So it's quite a deal for me if I make this work, electricity aside.

Thanks again, and sorry to bother. Have a great day!

Comment: Hello. do you need separate instances? maybe containers will do the jobs.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I don't know how containers work...

Comment: I have a home server and I did try KVM/Kimchi/WOK. It wokrs but it is havey for an old machine. Finally I moved to  server + dockers for better performance.

Comment: Yes! My first idea was a server yet it costs 5 times more to setup than a regular PC, and the demanding processing power of my VPS would be barely 10% of that, whereas would take 2 PCs at most to make it run 100%

Answer (score 1):

You should look into VMware ESXI, Proxmox and Truenas. They all support running multiple VIRTUAL machines at the same time. You can install one of the 3, then create multiple virtual machines with the needed resources and install the software you need to scrape.

** edit **

You can actually create one machine, set it up, then clone it's drive to the other virtual machines so you don't have to set each one up 1 by 1...

Comment: THANKS! This is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't know how to search for it. I've been googling for hours without knowing how to ask. (Not native english speaker). 

Thanks a lot!!